# Deduce number of components from chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory

How can one deduce the number of connectivity components from the chromatic polynomial of a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi_G(x) = \sum_{i = k}^{n + 1} a_i x^i$ be a chromatic polynomial of graph $G$. If $a_k \ne 0$ then graph $G$ has exactly $k$ components.

It is easy to see that chromatic polynomial of a graph is product of chromatics polynomials of its connected components. For each connected graph chromatic polynomial is divisible by $x$ and is not divisible by $x^2$.

The first is true because we can color all vertices in breads first search order (or the same for depth first search order) and the first vertex colored always has all $x$ colors available.

I wouldn't give strict proof that chromatic polynomial of connected graph is not divisible by $x^2$, but some reason for it is the following. Coloring vertices in BFS order we will have all $x$ colors available for the first colored vertex only. All other vertices will have less than $x$ colors, then sum over all choices for all vertices in sense of "one of previously used or a new color" can't be divisible by $x$ for all $x$.

Full proof of even more strong claim can be found [here](https://www.cs.elte.hu/blobs/diplomamunkak/mat/2009/hubai_tamas.pdf).